# How to watch for a property changed on a ref property in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, reference, listener

If you have a reference property like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public ref Vector2 Bar {
        get => ref bar;
    }
    private Vector2 bar;
}
```

Is there a way to listen for changes when Bar is modified like this?

```
    set {
        position = value;
        NotifyPositionChanged(value);
    }
```

Ideally all of the notify functionality would be encapsulated within the Foo class but none of the solutions I can think of maintain that encapsulation.

Is this impossible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define setter for a reference type property in C#.

Though you can create a method which will do the job like.

```
public void UpdateBar(Vector2 value)
{
    bar = value;
    NotifyPositionChanged(value);
}
```

Comment: But then if someone sets bar without the function, then the listener wont catch it

Comment: @SocratesHat, you are right. but you are making the without `set`. It has only `get`

Comment: Yeah you are right. I guess there is no solution that will catch all changes to the value.

Comment: @SocratesHat this is the best approach for your requirement